# Basic ng-click Example Not Working

Tags: angularjs

This is a very basic ng-click example. I can't seem to get it to work. Not sure what the issue is. I swear I've used Angular before! Here's a jsbin:

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/gidekozeki/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{1 + 2}}</h1>
  <button ng-click="alert('hello world')">Click me!</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Module:

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

Comment: add a controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be helpful to you while doing angularjs you should add the controller, In your case, I have created a function and passed a string value to show a message by the alert.

```js
var app=angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.showalert=function(str){
        alert(str);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-strict-di ng-controller="testCtrl">
<h1>{{1 + 2}}</h1>
<button ng-click="showalert('hai this is angularjs click event')"> click Me!..</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that using alert should work with or without a controller